# Perform arithmetic on a list in Scala

Tags: scala, list

I am new to Scala so please forgive me if I am overseeing something extremely basic here. I have the following:

```
case class Record(
ID: String,
Count: Double)

List(Record("ID1",10.0),Record("ID1",60.0),Record("ID2",50.0),Record("ID3",100.0),Record("ID3",20.0),Record("ID3",10.0))
```

where x is the ID and y is the Count in Record(x,y). I am able to print this list to the console with println(records).

**I am trying to output the following:**

```
ID1,70.0
ID2,50.0
ID3,130.0
```

**which is a summation of the count per ID group.** I would like to try the groupBy approach, but I am struggling to be able to parse the ID from each Record in my list in order to begin grouping the counts.

For example, I have considered:

```
val grouped = records.groupBy(<some_logic_here>)
```

but the problem is that the objects in the list have Record(x,y) wrapped around it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case class Record(ID: String,
                    Count: Double)

  val records = List(Record("ID1", 10.0), Record("ID1", 60.0), Record("ID2", 50.0), Record("ID3", 100.0), Record("ID3", 20.0),
    Record("ID3", 10.0))
```

here is the one liner:

```
  val ans = records.groupBy(_.ID).mapValues(_.map(_.Count).sum)

  ans.foreach(x => println(s"${x._1},${x._2}"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I now understand that in order to select the first field in Record(x,y), I just had to call it with _.ID, and to select the second field in Record(x,y), I needed to type _.Count. Sorry if that was basic knowledge, but it's new to me - thanks again.

Comment: @Bear you can also use anonymous function like records.groupBy(record=> records.ID).mapValues(value=> value.map(elem=>elem.Count).sum). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
case class Record(ID: String, Count: Double)
List(Record("1", 12), Record("1", 13), Record("2", 13))
  .groupBy(_.ID)
  .map(e => Record(e._1, e._2.map(e => e.Count).sum))
```

You need to groupBy(ID) and then you get an list, and then you need compute the sum.

Comment: Output is differed from the desired can you please update your answer.